# Stupid idea: Mac speech from PHP server?

Tags: php, macos, speech-synthesis

I want to synthesize Mac OS X speech, but I'm using a PC. Can I set up a PHP server on my Macbook at home, and have it synthesize text for me, and return it to me through a web request?

Like `http://mymacbook.com/speak.php?t=why+hello+there`

What secret PHP codes will unlock this possibility?
I know I can synthesize speech on the command line with `say -o "output.aiff" -f "input.txt"` but I need help with the connective tissue here.

**And no** - I do not want links to Cepstral or AT&T's online speech synthesizer, because I want to use special Mac speech synthesis syntax.

Comment: I think that is not a stupid idea

Comment: If and when you implement this... please share!

Comment: quick and dirty but it works :) http://www.baslerdesign.com/matt/say

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<?php
    file_put_contents('input.txt', $_GET['t']);
    exec('say -o output.aiff -f input.txt');
    header("Content-Type: audio/x-aiff");
    readfile("output.aiff");
    unlink("output.aiff");
    exit;
```

Comment: Caveat: multiple simultaneous requests can write to those files at once. At best this can have hilarious consequences, but if you don't care for that, use `tempnam()` or similar to generate unique temporary files for both input and output.

Comment: Cool - uh oh, what about getting the text from a HTTP GET request?